# How to make a variable but make than the variable doesn't run it-self

Tags: javascript, node.js

does anyone have an idea of how to make variables in javascript but than the content in it doesn't run itself till its called?

Example:

```
var x = console.log("Test")
```

If I make that the console will automatically print "Test", even if I don't call the "x", how can I change this?

Comment: Make it a function: `var x = () => console.log("Test");`

Comment: Create a function that you can then call later.

Answer (score 0):

Set the variable equal to a function that can be called at a later time in the program:

```
var x = () => console.log('Test');
```

This will not automatically print 'Test' to the console when the program is run.